# jQuery UI Accordion (or similar) with multiple header lines

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to show a list of messages to the user where the first two lines from each message are showing and they can click to see more.

So I was thinking the accordion would be an interesting way to do this.  The only problem is that I can only show the normal single line header row.  Is there a way I can show multiple lines or do I need to look for an alternative control like Kwicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive just given it a go and you can use a `< br >` inside of the `h3` to give it an extra line, or maybe try setting the wraping attributes for the css if you cant manually put a line break in.

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YY7ML/ for a basic example.

Or maybe I have misunderstood?

Comment: That's exactly what I need.  I can apply <spans> to properly format stuff... thx!